# how to receive a triangle shape output in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I was trying to write code with this output:

```
      1
    1 2 1
  1 2 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

This is what  I did :

```
program pascal
implicit none
integer i,j,k,p,n
write (*, '("input n: ")', advance="no")
read(*,*) n
do i=0,n-1
   p=1
   do j=1,n-1-i
      write(*,'(3X)', advance="no")
   enddo
   do k = 0,i
      write(*,'(I6)', advance="no") p
      p = p*(i-k)/(k+1)
   enddo
   write(*, '(/)')
end do
endprogram
```

which the output is pascal triangle. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. What is wrong with your code? Does the output look wrong? How wrong?

Comment: Do you want to have the pascal triangle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) or the output you show at the top of your question? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: To answer properly you need to clarify what output you want. But the "double spacing" problem is due to `write(*, '(/)')` which writes two end of record (i.e. end of line) markers, one due to `/` and one due completing and advancing I/O statement. Either simply `write( *, * )` or the slightly perverse `write(*, '(/)', Advance = 'No' )` will fix it.